# How to get a div to begin at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create an identical effect to the one shown on this website:

http://www.mintdigital.com

How do I get the div to begin at the bottom of the screen like that?

Comment: If you're looking to get an identical effect on that website, see how they do it. `Inspect element -> Look at DOM -> Oh they have a empty div with class[site-space] with a set height taking up loads of space, pushing the main content down`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's a `parallax` effect, the background can be in `position:fixed` and your content is in `position:absolute` with `top:90%`

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qgfDj/2/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:90%;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
}
```

Comment: Because you could just comment my answer instead of making a whole new answer just with 1 property change.

Comment: But your code doesn't work. Finally yes if you copy/paste my property. Good

Comment: Indeed and that is not worth to copy my answer and change that 1 property. You could have just commented that so I could change it and then it would be a good answer. Hence why you got a -1.

Comment: Now I remove your -1. I'm not a kid

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>put your stuff in here</p>
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:95%
}
```

This should do the trick.

Edit: or a different way to do it as MLeFevre says is to create a div above it, here is an example:

```
<div id="empty_space"></div>
<div id="container">
    <p>put your stuff in here</p>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
#empty_space{
    width:100%;
    height: 90%;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Try your code, it doesn't work because your container is 100px above the screen bottom, it's not the property `bottom` but the property `top`

Answer (score 0):

> > I am trying to create an identical effect to the one shown on this website:
> >
> > http://www.mintdigital.com
> >
> > How do I get the div to begin at the bottom of the screen like that?

Your question doesn't correspond your link.
If you want to put background which should be overlapped with DIV when scrolling, you should do something like this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="bkg"></div>
    <div class="content></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.bkg {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: url('/static/img/link_arrow.png');
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    background: white /* or anything you like */
    margin-top: 90%
}
```

If you want satisfy your question and just make bottom toolbar or something else fixed in bottom of the screen, you should do this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="foot-fixed"></div>
    <!-- rest content here -->
</body>
```

CSS

```
.foot-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Anyway, if you have working example, you always can reverse-engineer it with FireBug if you use Firefox, or built-in tool in any other popular browser.

Comment: Yes, but you have provided only one solution of possible two, whereas I preferred to cover ambiguity of the question and offered two different solutions for two meanings. Nevertheless, your jsFiddle is more complete and accurate =)